# iOS - Can we skip adding font capability if we want to install fonts using CTFontManagerRegister apple ios xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, truetype

For iOS, Can we use below methods to download the fonts without adding Fonts capability(to avoid asking user permission), if in case you only want to download fonts for your app and not systemwide?
And is it possible the downloaded fonts will be used only by our app and not system wide any app?

```
{
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontURLs(_:_:_:_:)
    
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontDescriptors(_:_:_:_:)
    
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontsWithAssetNames(_:_:_:_:_:)
}
```

Referring [the apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-custom-fonts?changes=_7)

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?